# How to make Jenkins to use private key and passphrase to run Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am using Jenkins to run some Ansible playbooks. One of the simple tests I did was to have the playbook to cat the fstab file on a remote server:

The playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: "tesst-1-server"

  tasks:

  - name: dislpay /etc/fstab
    shell: cat /etc/fstab
    register: fstab_reg

  - debug: msg="{{ fstab_reg.stdout }}"
```

In Jenkins, I have a freestyle project, it uses Invoke Ansible Playbook to call the above playbook, and the project credentials was setup with a different: ansible-user. This is different from the default user-jenkins that runs Jenkins. User ansible-user can ssh to all my servers. I have ansible-user setup in Jenkins Credential with its private key and passphrase. But when I run the project, I got an error:

```
[update_fstab] $ /usr/bin/ansible-playbook google/ansible/test-scripts/test/sub_book.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh14117407503194058572.key -u ansible-user
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details

fatal: [test-1-server]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible-user@test-1-server: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
```

I am not quiet sure what exactly the error is saying as I have setup the private key and passphrase to ansible-user's credentials. What does the group names in the message mean? Because this is done through Jenkins, I am not sure how to do the -vvv as it suggested.

How can I make Jenkins to pass the private key and passphrase to the Ansible playbook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the "issue". After I switched to a different user other than ansible-user, the playbook worked. Interesting thing is that when I created the private key pairs for ansible-user, I used "-m PEM" and it should be good for Jenkins.